# OpenPGM problems getting gstreamer up and running

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

very recently has started examining openPGM implementation as a solution to implementing reliable multicasting in my home network. I've downloaded the various OpenPGM implementations and even have used the loopback examples working.

Then I wanted to see how openPGM works with gstreamer. So I downloaded from the link (http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/downloads/detail?name=gstpgm-2.0.4.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) the gstpgm zip that contains gsteamer plugins and at that point started having problems getting it up and running.

when I run scons using the default SConstruct I get the following error:

```
halford@ubuntu:~/gstp_heiher$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o libgstpgm.so -pipe -pthread -shared gstpgm.os gstpgmsrc.os gstpgmsink.os -lpgm -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lxml2 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpgm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [libgstpgm.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

When I comment out the LIB=[libpgm] statement in the SConstruct file the thing compiles but when I run the ./smokesrc.sh script I got the following error:

```
halford@ubuntu:~/gstp_heiher$ scons
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "pgmsink"
halford@ubuntu:~/gstp_heiher$ gedit SConstruct 
halford@ubuntu:~/gstp_heiher$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o libgstpgm.so -pipe -pthread -shared gstpgm.os gstpgmsrc.os gstpgmsink.os -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lxml2 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
scons: done building targets.

halford@ubuntu:~/gstp_heiher$ ./smokesrc.sh 
(gst-plugin-scanner:3991): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin './libgstpgm.so': ./libgstpgm.so: undefined symbol: pgm_gsi_create_from_addr

(gst-plugin-scanner:3991): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstpgm.so': /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstpgm.so: undefined symbol: g_thread_new
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "pgmsink"
```

Could anybody help me here?

PS: I've communicated this message to openPGM forum but no response. It seems to be inactive for years.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to install development version of libpgm: `sudo apt-get install libpgm-dev`.
And uncomment `LIB=[libpgm]` back.

Comment: Hmm. Tried it but on ubuntu 10.04 it seems that the package is unavailable. Cechked like this: sudo apt-cache search libpgm-dev* and got nothing back.

Comment: Okay! Downloaded new Ubuntu version (12.04), the libpgm + installed the openpgm lib release-5.2.122 from openPGM and the gstreamer application worked fine!  Please mind that without the command: sudo apt-get install gstreamer-0.10,   the gstreamer won't work.   Thanks a lot! Spiros

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done the bare build of openPGM, with flags and debugging options enabled.
BUt i had it on ubuntu 12.04,, but shouldnt be prob with the earlier versions as well.

if you are not trying to change anythings in the code, I would suggest to go for package available.
or else can build with scons easily..
scons works fine without any changes to the script,, unless its being run on Mac.
Lemme know what errors are you facing(lets not waste time in addressing the same issues as before)